# Register users synchronously during context seed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In my ASP.Net MVC 5 project, I have a custom initializer class:

```
class CustomInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<GhazanetContext>
```

I want to seed the context with several users. The problem is that the new MVC 5 is `async` and whatever I try to do fails. Here's my code which attempts to create a user:

```
    private void AddRestaurant(RegisterRestaurantViewModel model, DBContext db)
    {
        User user = new User(model.UserName) { Addresses = new List<Address>(), Role = "Restaurant" };
        user.Addresses.Add(model.Address);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                await Users.Create(user); // GETS STUCK HERE

                var newUser = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == user.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
                var restaurant = new Restaurant(model) { User = newUser };
                db.Restaurants.Add(restaurant);
                db.SaveChanges();
                await Secrets.Create(new UserSecret(model.UserName, model.Password));
                await Logins.Add(new UserLogin(user.Id, IdentityConfig.LocalLoginProvider, model.UserName));

                const string role = "Restaurant";
                if (!await Roles.RoleExists(role))
                    await Roles.CreateRole(new Role(role));

                await Roles.AddUserToRole(role, user.Id);
            }).RunSynchronously();
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it gets stuck in the line above but when I run it in the website and register users, it works perfectly. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: you have a typo for 'stuck', it is not 'stock'

Comment: @DarthVader LOL. Thanks. That's what happens when you post a question between 2 parts of your sleep :D BTW, I was in stocks at that time, maybe that's why!

Comment: Does this actually compile? The built-in `Users`/`Roles` classes do not have `async` methods.

Comment: @StephenCleary Yes it does. I'm using ASP.Net MVC **5**. The new version is `async` and doesn't have sync version. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `ExecuteSynchronously`, neither of which should be used in `async` code.

The best way to invoke `async` code is to invoke it *from* `async` code, as such:

```
private async Task AddRestaurantAsync(RegisterRestaurantViewModel model, DBContext db)
{
    User user = new User(model.UserName) { Addresses = new List<Address>(), Role = "Restaurant" };
    user.Addresses.Add(model.Address);
    await Users.Create(user);
    var newUser = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == user.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
    var restaurant = new Restaurant(model) { User = newUser };
    db.Restaurants.Add(restaurant);
    db.SaveChanges();
    await Secrets.Create(new UserSecret(model.UserName, model.Password));
    await Logins.Add(new UserLogin(user.Id, IdentityConfig.LocalLoginProvider, model.UserName));

    const string role = "Restaurant";
    if (!await Roles.RoleExists(role))
        await Roles.CreateRole(new Role(role));

    await Roles.AddUserToRole(role, user.Id);
}
```

This does have a cascading effect through your code base (the callers of `AddRestaurantAsync` must themselves be `async`, etc), but it's the easiest and cleanest way of calling `async` code. Various hacks exist for calling asynchronous code in a synchronous manner, but it's easy to get into deadlock situations and even if you get it right it will impact the scalability of your site.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was not that I didn't know how to use `async`. I was trying to run the `async` methods such as `Users.Create(user);` synchronously. However, when I read your answer, it occurred to me that I sinc the return type of the event thandler of `Seed` function is `void`, I could mark it as `async` without changing its signature. It works. However, for some reason I get an error after the database is initialized. It's fully functional though so there's not much problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori: You should also avoid `async void` unless it is absolutely necessary. I recommend you contact the EF team and ask them what the recommended practice is.

Comment: Hmmm. Do you know a direct contact method like twitter of some of the devs? What is your recommended method to contact them?

Comment: @AlirezaNoori: I'd first check the EF project pages for contact info. If there's nothing there, try the MSDN forums.

Answer (score 0):

You can run async task synchronously: `var result = Users.Create(user).Result`